# How to fill multiple holes?

Tags: modeling

I'm wondering if there is a way to fill holes correctly like the next one

[image]

In order to make it automatic an not monually like this, by selecting each edges and fill them with F

[image]

I've tried fill it with F and F alternatives (Ctrl +F) and always I have results like this

[image]

Thanks, it would be too helpful :)

Comment: Try using grid fill

Comment: first you have to select 4 vertices and press 'f' to fill the first face and then press consecutively 'f' will fill the others to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to create a clean mesh:

1. Fix the regions I pointed out. *(these faces are currently overlapping)*
2. Select the edges you want to bridge but deselect the edges shown in the image.
3. Press **CTRL+E** and select *'**bridge edge loops**'*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try selecting a portion and using Bridge Edge Loops